# in the command "pip install -r requirements.txt" what does '-r' meant? same as in "python3 -m pip install something" what does '-m' meant?

Tags: python, pip

I searched before asking this question but i did get exact answer. can anyone let me know where to read about these operators and others like same as this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22pip+install+-r+requirements.txt%22+what+%22-r%22 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+what+%22-m%22

Answer (score 1):

Run `python -h` to get a list of arguments and their function.

`-m` is used to run a library module as a script. In this case you're running `pip` as a script.

`-r` is from `pip` so you can do `pip -h` for more detail. `pip install` also has options, so you can do  `pip install -h` for even more detail (you see where this is going). The general idea is `-r` is meant to install from a requirements file and are treated as dependencies of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--help` to print out the possible set of arguments that a command can take. If you use `pip install --help`, it will show the arguments and their meaning. See below for the meaning of -r flag:

`-r, --requirement <file>    Install from the given requirements file. This option can be used multiple times.`

Answer (score 0):

`-r` is used as a way to tell pip to install packages from the requirements file (Usage: `pip3 install -r <file>`. `-r` can also be written as `--requirement`

you can use `pip install --help` to learn about more arguments you can use with pip install

Answer (score 0):

It means **install packages from the given requirements file**:

```
pip install -r <file>
or 
pip install --requirement <file>
```